# React switching between lists with same class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have main component which has 4 subcomponents and I wish to pass states props and functions between them. The thing is that in subcomponent List I wish to be able to get access only to interior of the list with the class ".title" Is it any way to jump between same classes in react as it was possible in jQuery? something like this next(), prev() and find()? I tried to find any way but I have failed so far.

```
class List extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        title: ""
    }
}

    render() {
        return (
    <div>
        <ul className="List">
          <li>
           <ul className="song">
             <li className="time">
               3:16
             </li>
             <li className="title" onClick= {this.handleSong}> Title I want to pass
             </li>
           </ul>
          </li>
    <ul className="List">
          <li>
           <ul className="song">
             <li className="time">
               4:16
             </li>
             <li className="title" onClick= {this.handleSong}> next Title I want to pass
             </li>
           </ul>
          </li>
    </div>
```

and here is function where I can get access to one element but don't know how to switch to next one

```
handleSong = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            title: event.currentTarget.textContent,
        })
        event.preventDefault()
    }
```

UPDATED:
I changed my code as you suggested and now it looks like this:
Inside main component:

```
class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isClicked: true,
            playerDisplayed: true,
            title: "Still Don't Know",
            songs: []
        }
    }



componentDidMount() {
                const url = "http://localhost:3000/ListOfSongs"
                fetch(url)
                    .then(resp => resp.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        this.setState({
                            songs: data
                        })
                        console.log(data);
                    });
            }

        return (
             <div className="container">
               <div className="wrapperList">
                  <HeaderList
                    handleReturn={this.handleReturn.bind(this)}/>
                  <ul className="songsList">
                     {this.state.songs.map(e =>
                     <SongsList id={e.id} title={e.title} time={e.time}
                     handleChooseSong={this.handleChooseSong.bind(this)}
                     playerDisplayed={this.state.playerDisplayed}/>
                                    )}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
                    )
                }
```

SongList component :

```
 <li id={this.props.id}>
    <ul className="song">
     <li className="timeAndBand">
       {this.props.time} || {this.props.band}
     </li>
     <li className="title" onClick={this.props.handleChooseSong}>
           {this.props.title}
     </li>
     <li className="icons">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="share-alt"className="shareBtn" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
           </svg>
           <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart"
             className="heartBtn" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            </svg>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Each song should be a component:

```
<Song id={song.id} title={song.title} time={song.time} 
   handleClick={someHandlerInParent} />
```

in `<Song />` of course html and

```
onClick={ this.props.handleClick( this.props.id ) }
```

This way you can pass to List component (parent) information about which song was selected, filter by id, get title, time, whatever. Render list using map, you can tell Song (by prop) that is currently selected to render with another style/class ... NOT BY getting/selecting DOM node and adding/removing classes - it's a lot simpler and more powerfull with react - render fn can have logic to choose style, show additional options (components).

Search for more tutorials, even TODO examples - react is not another templating engine - you have to learn `thinking in react`. It's hard to just start writting code w/o some knowledge.

UPDATE: Look at this example - component can contain much more (complex) data w/o need to 'artificially pumping it into html' (each template engines needs it). You can show in html only part of data and still use all 'behind scene'! **No more searching for id (next/prev/n-th child...), get value, prop, state ... or manually roll-back changes (grrr#$%)**. You can manipulate objects w/o `hand tools`, not step by step (error prone) - `with react you have automation` 'CNC' for this.

Comment: hey, sorry for late answer but i got some home issues and then tried to crack this what you have just said, thank you for your suggestion and I did as you said, I will put my code below, I created in my main component SongList and inside SongList I put html with this.props.title/.time/.band/.id etc, actually it works very good and code looks simpler! I haven't thought about it, Thank you:) but can you tell me how to actually switch to next id after clicking? With this solution every list has own id but how to exactly switch to next or previous id?

Comment: **Bind handlers in constructor, not in render.**
  It's a list/container responsibility to provide all needed data/handlers into items/components. You can change `map` into `for` loop and provide next/prev ids but probably better will be pass handlePrev/handleNext and find/calculate next/prev from current id.